# CSS change line when space is full

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple question . This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/dc4b7/1/) . I dont want a scroller if space is full for example in my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/dc4b7/1/) text `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`is in the same line but it should change the line if space is full like

```
abcdefghijklmno
pqrstuvwxyz
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong here??

```
 <div id="mainContainer">   
    <div id="headlineText">  
        <div class="inner">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
    </div>
```

i want output like [this](http://i.share.pho.to/b7ba3fc6_o.jpeg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `#headlineText`, add:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
width:280px;
```

You had `width` set to `20px` which was the problem :)

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dc4b7/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this would be to use CSS  on the containing div.

```
.inner {
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Odd. Here is my fiddle - don't know if it would help or not - http://jsfiddle.net/fpMRr/

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the following CSS property on inner: `word-wrap: break-word;` If it's still overflowing, the CSS on the containers might be contributing to that. Try to rebuild the container CSS from the ground up. Maybe that will fix it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4a3rx/